# Почему не выполняется вторая функция написанная после main?

Tags: c, функции

В нижеприведённом коде вторая функция не выполняется, будто бы её там вообще нет. Ума не приложу, в чём дело. Использую Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2.

```
int main()
{
    int a;
    a=30;
    printf("%d\n\n",a);
    system("PAUSE");        
    return a;
}

int kek()
{
    int b;
    b=40;
    printf("%d\n\n",b);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: дайте угадаю -- вы считаете, что код должен последовательно выполняться.

Comment: Угадали. А это не так? Чужие коды, которые я смотрел, именно так и выглядели - функции шли последовательно друг за другом. Ну и опыт на паскале сказывается.

Comment: А разве в паскале также все объявленные функции саме по себе выполняются?

Comment: чтобы функция выполнялась ее необходимо вызвать (кроме main)

Comment: Понял ошибку, спасибо.

Comment: @Аноним, опыт на паскале у вас наверное такой же как и на С++ )))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Точкой входа в программу является функция `main`. Она вызывается при запуске вашей программы.
В C функция `main` без параметров должна быть объявлена как

```
int main( void )
{
    //...
}
```

Из стандарта C (5.1.2.2.1 Program startup):

> 1 The function called at program startup is named main. The
>   implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be
>   defined with a return type of int and with no parameters:
>
> int main(void) { /* ... */ }

Все остальные функции получают управление только лишь, если они вызываются в вашей программе.

Если вы используете библиотечные функции, то вы должны включить в программу заголовки, где эти функции объявляются.

Ваша программа могла бы выглядеть следующим образом:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int kek();

int main( void )
{
    int a;
    a=30;

    printf("%d\n\n",a);

    kek();

    system("PAUSE");        
    return a;
}

int kek()
{
    int b;
    b=40;

    printf("%d\n\n",b);

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я вообще пытался понять как работает return, кажется понял, он возвращает какое-либо значение в вызвавшую его функцию. А как можно это значение дальше использовать? Вот например, значение переменной a из функции f1 возвращается в main, как я могу дальше эту цифру 30 использовать? `int main()
{
f1();
}

int f1()
{
    int a;
    a=30;       
    return a;
}` Что-то я не могу в столбик код написать, вместо новой строки отправляется сообщение.

Comment: @Аноним Если функция, имеет тип возвращаемого значения, отличного от void, то в предложении return вы должны задать выражение, которые преобразуется к возвращаемому типу функции и передается в вызывающую функцию. В вызывающей функции вы можете присвоить это значение некоторой переменной. Например,  int x = f1(); printf( "x = %d\n", x );

Answer (score 2):

Возможно так будет работать так как Вы хотели:

```
int f1(void)
{
    int a;
    a=30;
    printf("%d\n\n",a);
    system("PAUSE");        
    return a;
}

int f2(void)
{
    int b;
    b=40;
    printf("%d\n\n",b);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
f1();
f2();
}
```

В main вызываем необходимые функции.

Порядок выполнения можно также изменить с помощью директивы

```
#pragma startup имя_функции приоритет=64-255
```

тем самым будут выполняться иные функции в желаемом порядке.

Comment: Спасибо! Выходит если функций в программе должно быть больше одной, то main используется только для вызова других функций?

Comment: @Аноним не обязательно, но и захламлять main не стоит.

Comment: @Аноним термин "должно" тут неприменим. Это вопрос удобства, целесообразности и читаемости кода. В отдельные процедуры и функции как правило выносятся повторяющиеся части кода или части с выраженной изолированной функциональностью. Например если программа читает текст из файла, форматирует его и распечатывает на экран, то целесообразно сделать отдельные функции (и процедуры) для чтения, форматирования и печати.

Comment: @dsnk Было бы хорошо объяснить автору, почему его предположение неверно и код не работает, чем просто подсовывать готовое решение.

Comment: @Krom Stern судя по комментариям к вопросу, автор уже понял причину проблемы.

Comment: @AnatolyNikolaev цель сайта SO собрание базы качественных вопросов и ответов, а не помощь конкретному "Анониму"